# How can I use a CAST in an ExcludeConstraint in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In PostgreSQL I can create a table with an exclusion constraint involving a `CAST` (the `CAST` is necessary because the `UUID` type doesn't have a default operator class for `gist`):

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE TABLE example (
  id         UUID,
  some_range INT4RANGE,
  EXCLUDE USING gist (CAST("id" AS TEXT) WITH =, some_range WITH &&)
);
```

I can't figure out how to accomplish the same thing in SQLAlchemy. I tried this:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import (
    UUID, INT4RANGE, ExcludeConstraint, TEXT
)

class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example'
    id = Column(UUID)
    some_range = Column(INT4RANGE)
    __table_args__ = (
        ExcludeConstraint(
            (cast('id', TEXT), '='), ('some_range', '&&')
        ),
    )
```

But I get the error `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't add unnamed column to column collection`.

How can I get SQLAlchemy to use the `CAST` in the `ExcludeConstraint`? Alternatively, how I can use raw SQL to define the exclude constraint on the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3454, the workaround (for versions prior to 1.0.6) is

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.elements import quoted_name

    ExcludeConstraint(
        (Column(quoted_name('CAST("id" AS TEXT)', quote=False)), '='), ('some_range', '&&')
    ),
```